# How does one determine the time unit in numpy.datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, datetime64

I can't see how to reveal the units for numpy.datetime64. Say:

`t=np.datetime64(123456789, 'ms' )`

What's the method to tell me the units are 'ms'?

Comment: Another aside comment, why should this matter? The objects with different internal unit formats are still interoperable.

Comment: I think I missed your first comment

Comment: It matters for example when trying to serialize the data efficiently.

Answer (score 7):

As of NumPy 1.14 (Jan 2018), the [`datetime_data`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.datetime.html) function is available to return a tuple of `(units, number of base units in step)` for a given datetime64 dtype:

```
>>> dt = np.datetime64(123456789, 'ns')
>>> np.datetime_data(dt)
('ns', 1)
>>> dt_units = np.datetime)data(dt)[0]
>>> print(dt_units)
'ns'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query using:

```
np.dtype(t)
#dtype('<M8[ms]')
```

from where you can see the units in `ms`.